# Matching at least and at most with regular expressions in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match a string (call it `$word`) with at least 5 a's and at most 15 b's. How do we do that using regular expression?

```
$word =~ /xxxxx/
```

such that what comes instead of `xxxxx`?

Comment: Do you need to do it in a single regular expression?

Comment: It would be better to do in a single one.

Comment: Why is a single regex better? Is this homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the regex I'd use:

```
if ($word =~ m/  # Match word having 5 A's min and 15 B's max.
            ^                       # Anchor to start of string.
            (?=(?:[^Aa]*[Aa]){5})   # Assert 5 A's minimum.
            (?!(?:[^Bb]*[Bb]){16})  # Assert 15 B's maximum.
            .*                      # Safe to match whole string.
    /sx) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the way that you've presented this, you can't use a single regular expression easily. You can count characters with `tr///`:

```
use v5.10;

my $word = 'aabaabaa';

my $a = $word =~ tr/a//;
my $b = $word =~ tr/b//;

say do {
    if( $a >= 5 and $b <= 15 ) { "Matched with $a a's and $b b's" }
    else                       { "Missed with $a a's and $b b's" }
    };
```

You could use the match operator in scalar context to move along the string and count what you find, but that's not that satisfying:

```
use v5.10;

my $word = 'aabaabaa';
my %seen;

while( $word =~ m/(a|b)/g ) {
    $seen{$1}++;
    }

say do {
    my( $a, $b ) = @seen{ qw( a b ) };
    if( $a >= 5 and $b <= 15 ) { "Matched with $a a's and $b b's" }
    else                       { "Missed with $a a's and $b b's" }
    };
```

If you don't like the `while`, you might do it like this:

```
my @matches = $word =~ m/(a|b)/g;
$seen{$_}++ for @matches;
```

Using the regex like this allows you to find multiple characters or patterns, which `tr///` doesn't (although this doesn't handle pattern overlaps):

```
my @matches = $word =~ m/(cat|dog)/g;
$seen{$_}++ for @matches;
```

However, I usually see this problem presented as looking for runs of characters, so there are no more than 5 consecutive *a*'s and fewer than 15 consecutive *b*'s. Since I think you're doing homework, I'll tell you about the problem, but I'm not giving you a full solution.

There are a lot of tricks there because it's easy to match a maximum number of characters, but you need to ensure that the surrounding text doesn't spoil the problem. I'm going to start with *b*, but look for a maximum of 5 so I don't have to type out so many *b*'s. The number doesn't matter though. If you have the string `bbbbbbb`, you can match no more than five *b*'s in three ways: **bbbbb**bb, b**bbbbb**b, and bb**bbbbb**. You have to ensure that the text around your match is not what it shouldn't be.

You might think that's really simple:

```
my $b_regex = qr/
    (?:
        (?<!b)
        (?:b{0,5})
        (?!b)
    )
    /;
```

However, Perl uses an NFA regex engine, which means that it finds the leftmost, longest match. The leftmost part is the problem because that's more important than longest. Consider the string `bbb......bbbbbb`. Perl will match the `bbb` portion at the beginning because it's the leftmost part that satisfies the regex. You can fix that with a variable width lookahead that scans the rest of the string looking for a run of six *b*'s:

```
my $b_regex = qr/
    (?:
        (?<!b)
        (?:b{0,5})
        (?!b)
    )
    (?!.*b{5,})
    /sx;
```

That works! Well, no, it doesn't. That only looks ahead. Perl's NFA will float along the string looking for another place to match. This regex fails with `bbbbbb...bbb...bbbb` where a long run of *b*'s is before the spot where that regex will match.

So, you change plans. If any number of *b*'s includes 0 (tricky!), you can use a negative lookahead to not match 6 consecutive *b*'s. This is anchored to the beginning of the string so we can scan the entire string without changing the match position (just hold on for a moment):

```
my $b_regex = qr/
    \A
    (?!.*b{6})
    /sx;
```

If you have to match at least one *b*, we can have a positive lookahead for that. Now that anchor makes sense. You scan the string looking for a disqualifying run of *b*'s, don't change the match position, then look for at least one *b*:

```
my $b_regex = qr/
    \A
    (?!.*b{6})
    (?=.*b)
    /sx;
```

Now you have to think about the *a*'s. That's almost easy. The trick is that the right number of *a*'s can come before or after the match for the *b*'s. Again, you can use a lookahead to scan the string. You don't need to do that much work because you don't are if there are more than 5 of them, so any 5 will do:

```
my $ab_regex = qr/
    \A
    (?!.*b{6})
    (?=.*b)
    (?=.*a{5})
    /sx;
```

Now, I've left you with a half a solution because I've specifically left out parts that would allow you to capture the parts that matched and know where they are in the string. This will only tell you that the pattern matches.

There's another benefit with these lookaheads. You can find overlapping matches because you are never advancing the match position and each new lookahead scans the entire string.